# Distinguir columnas en consulta join laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente codigo :

```
$datos = DB::table('emple_inf')
            ->join('emple_lab','emple_inf.ced_inf','=','emple_lab.ced_lab')
            ->get();

foreach($datos as $dato)
{

$quincena = new GrabarQuincena;
$quincena->cedula = $dato->ced_lab;
$quincena->porcentaje = $dato->anticipo;
$quincena->sueldo = $dato->sueldo;
$quincena->total = ($dato->sueldo*$dato->anticipo)/100;
$quincena->fecha = date('d/m/Y');
$quincena->save();


}

return "Bieeeen";
```

Si tengo 2 tablas y en las 2 tengo una columna con el mismo nombre...como utilizar la columna de "x" tabla ya sea de una o de otra ?

Si quiero utlizar la columna "cedula" de la tabla 2 como lo haria si las 2 columnas tienen el mismo nombre.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que deberías usar Eloquent y no el Query Builder, para que sea más sencillo.

Comment: Hago lo que dice Shaz y me lanza este error, por eso la pregunta: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3sSJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3sSJ.png)

Comment: Ahí yo no veo que hagas lo que Shaz te recomendó, el habla sobre las relaciones de Eloquent, lo cual puedes ver [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Usando Eloquent (definiendo las relaciones) es muy sencillo, por medio de Eager Loading para cargar la relación con la otra tabla (modelo):

```
$datos = EmpleInf::with('empleLab')->get();
```

Si quieres acceder al campo cedula de la «primera tabla», sería:

```
$dato->cedula;
```

Si deseas acceder al mismo campo en la «segunda tabla», sería:

```
$dato->empleLab->cedula;
```

Revisa la documentación de Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships